# Terraform not uploading Lambda code zip file to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

Right now I have the following in my `main.tf`:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "terraform_lambda" {
  filename = "tf_lambda.zip"
  function_name = "tf_lambda"
  role = "lambda_basic_execution"
  handler = "tf_lambda.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("tf_lambda.zip"))}"
  runtime = "python3.6"
}
```

My directory structure is like so:

```
.
|-- main.tf
|-- tf_lambda.zip
|-- tf_lambda
    └── tf_lambda.py
```

When I run `terraform apply` and then, in the console, go to the lambda created the code section is empty and it invites me to upload a zip file. How do I make sure the code actually gets uploaded?

Comment: Can you try putting tf_lambda.py file in the root of the zip (instead of the directory) and share the results?

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 the zip is made with the following command: `zip tf_lambda.zip tf_lambda/tf_lambda.py` so it should already be in the root of the zip.

Comment: Have you tried executing the Lambda? This is from memory, however, when uploaded from Zip you might not get the inline code editor.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may also try this using archive_file, https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/archive/d/archive_file.html
So that when you run "terraform apply" the file will be re-zipped and uploaded.

```
data "archive_file" "zipit" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "tf_lambda/tf_lambda.py"
  output_path = "tf_lambda.zip"
}


resource "aws_lambda_function" "terraform_lambda" {
  function_name = "tf_lambda"
  role = "lambda_basic_execution"
  handler = "tf_lambda.lambda_handler"
  filename = "tf_lambda.zip"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.zipit.output_base64sha256}"
  runtime = "python3.6"
}
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks so much!

Comment: This only works if your entire build process is just zipping a file/folder though. More complex build processes (e.g. Java lambdas that have to build a jar) would have to rely on external tools. If you are a Terraform Enterprise client it is even worse as you probably don't control the environment where Terraform runs (so no gradle/maven/java...)

Comment: updated url: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/archive/latest/docs/data-sources/archive_file