# terraform, lambda. how to ensure zipfile is always created

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

We have several developers, each deploying a lambda function (from their own computer) via terraform to a shared account. Terraform state files are in an S3 bucket for consistency. As we're deploying from different computers, the function zipfile may not exist locally. How can I make sure the function zip is always created?

I'm using the following code in a terraform module

```
resource "null_resource" "zipfile" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.code_dependencies]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "cd ${var.source_dir} && zip -r function.zip * -x *.zip"
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "function" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.zipfile]
  filename         = "${var.source_dir}/function.zip"
  function_name    = var.function_name
  role             = aws_iam_role.lambda_function_role.arn
  handler          = var.handler
  source_code_hash = filesha256("${var.source_dir}/function.zip")
  runtime = var.runtime
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50357651/terraform-not-uploading-lambda-code-zip-file-to-aws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use **triggers** argument of null_resource. Setting a unique value such as the timestamp would trigger the command every time. The downside is that it will run even if the there is no change in the source.

```
resource "null_resource" "zipfile" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = "cd ${var.source_dir} && zip -r ${local.filename} * -x *.zip"
  }

  triggers = {
     always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}
```